# How do I accept international payments using Stripe as an Individual?

Tags: freelance-websites, payments, billing, money

I have recently started doing freelance work and received my first commission, I have completed my artwork and send a payment link using Stripe, but stripe seems to not accept international payments for individuals. It looks like I have to register as a company to accept payments. Are there any other websites that will help me accept payment online other than stripe as an individual I tried RazorPay but it also does not allow me to create international payment links? How do you guys get paid for your artwork? I cannot use PayPal because it does not authenticate my bank and the customer service does not help me.

[Accept International Payments from India | striprDocs](https://stripe.com/docs/india-accept-international-payments)

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

I was dealing with this problem for 13 years. I think PayPal has restrictions for non-US or non-European citizens to have an account and even more restrictions if your country is a third-world country. Online payments websites have more restrictions for you because the money can be illicit, so they put this kind of restriction to avoid money laundering. this problem of Region or Requirements Restrictions also happens to me with Stripe, Venmo, CashApp, and Google Wallet.

My better recommendation is to use PayPal, which I and a lot of freelancers friends use. Also, this is the payment method favourite on upwork.com and freelancer.com.

*I recommend you research about a Virtual Credit Card. I used this to verify my PayPal account.*

At the moment, I am using PayPal goods-and-services to be paid for my services and all is normal. I receive money without restriction. It's just bad for the commissions and withdrawal for local currency.